# Pass function as a condition inside the find method express and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a collection of restaurants and i want to return restaurants where distance is less than X. each restaurant has its latitude and longitude as **lat** and **lon** and i'am passing the user's position fro the frontend. I am using **TomTom Route API** to calculate distance.

This is the function that calculate the distance

```
export const getDistance = async(res, mylat, mylong, lat, long) => {
  try {
    const distance = await axios.get(`https://api.tomtom.com/routing/1/calculateRoute/${mylat},${mylong}:${lat},${long}/json?key=${APIKEY}`)
    return res.status(200).json(position.data.routes[0].summary.lengthInMeters)
  } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).json({message: error.message})
  }
}
```

And this is the function to get the restaurants

```
export const getRestaurants = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const restaurants = await RestaurantModel.find()
    res.status(200).json(restaurants)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({message: error.message})
  }
}
```

How can i use the **getDistance()** function to return restaurants where distance is less than **X Meters**?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming "RestaurantModel" is your MongoDB collection that you're connected to...
I don't think it's possible to use a function like getDistance in a database query directly (and if it is, I'm not sure it's more efficient, though this seems like it could be a very time consuming operation regardless). So, what you can do is query the database for all the relevant restaurants (like you're doing) and then with `const restaurants` array, use javascript's [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) function ([find](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp) might work too) to refine the database results per the getDistance function after the fact. Then you can send the resulting restaurants within a certain distance to the user.  Good luck!

P.S. You may also want to tack on a `.toArray()` to the end of that database query.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).